# Rundeck Cluster with Mysql Backend Run Job Error - An Error Occurred Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

Tags: mysql, rundeck

I have setup a Rundeck cluster with Mysql backend.

```
VM1: Rundeck1 + Mysql data node 1
VM2: Rundeck2 + Mysql data node 2
VM3: Management Node
```

NFS: Projects folder shared + /var/logs shared

my.cnf settings:

```
[client]
port = 3306
socket = /tmp/mysql.sock

[mysqld]
port = 3306
socket = /tmp/mysql.sock

default-storage-engine=NDBCLUSTER

ndbcluster

innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 120
lock-wait-timeout= 120

[mysql_cluster]
ndb-connectstring= xx.x.xxx.xx # location of management server
```

Whenever I create a project and run the jobs it keeps giving the following error:

```
An Error Occurred
Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
```

But the jobs runs fine and gets completed. This I can see from the activity section of the project in rundeck.

I have already set the following too:

```
 @@GLOBAL.tx_isolation, @@tx_isolation, @@session.tx_isolation;
```

Kindly Help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to increase the value of *innodb_lock_wait_timeout* to a value according to your requirements.. try value to 3000 example.

SET GLOBAL innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 3000;

120 looks so low..

also try *show processlist* command and kill some of the long running queries using kill command